# Firebase database and app localization

Tags: localization, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a quiz game for both iOS & Android platforms and I want to be able to handle localization.

I am using Firebase's realtime database solution in order to pull all of the question the game is going to have.
I am hardcoding the questions into the Firebase's database and every question object has 2 parameters:

**ID** - Obviously

**Text** - The question text itself e.g. "Who was John Kennedy?"

I am having hard time thinking about how to localize the questions I am pulling from Firebase. Obviously if the app is localized as Spanish I want to get the questions text translated to Spanish.

How do I go about it?

Thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 7):

Database like this...

```
{
  "en": { "Q1": "Who was JFK?"    },
  "es": { "Q1": "¿Quién era JFK?" }
}
```

Accessed like this (JavaScript)...

```
var locale = fooLocale() || 'en'; // get locale, fallback to English
var firedb = firebase.database(); // init database
var content = firedb.ref(locale); // get reference to locale data

content.child('Q1').on('value', function (snapshot) {       // request Q1
  document.getElementById('Q1').innerHTML = snapshot.val(); // set UI text
});
```