# Firebase Multi-Language Support

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, localization, multilingual

I have a firebase application, I want it to support Arabic and English language, my app has multiple databases, I know how to make localization for local texts and strings, but I want to ask how I can make localization for data that I get it from Firebase?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I'm wondering something similar. I think the way you would have to do this is how you structure your data. you could have something like a collectionName_EN and collectionName_AR which each would house your different languages. Other then this I don't think there is any built in solution for language.

Comment: Just to add to the same idea here, you could have a sub collection on any of your documents to store the different language text. I would play around with those ideas to see if one works for you. It really depends on how you get your documents.

Comment: There is a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049367/1744705. He created ENGLISH and SPANISH databases seperately. Then he checked device language and pulled data from firebase respect to this info.